# How is this variable value changing in the function?

Tags: c, variables, gcc, memory, opencl

I have this code:

```
device_params_t *device_params = malloc(sizeof(device_params_t));

get_device_params(device_params, platform_id, workWithUser ? "check_pdfs_user" : "check_pdfs_owner", program_buffer, program_size);

int password_len = strlen(password_prefix) + password_digits + strlen(password_suffix);

unsigned int prefix_length = strlen(password_prefix), suffix_length = strlen(password_suffix);
unsigned long count;

// while (number < max_password) {
    count = max_password - number;
    count = count > batch_size ? batch_size : count;
    printf("%lu\n", count);
    run_on_gpu(device_params, params, number, password_prefix, prefix_length, password_suffix, suffix_length, password_len, count, &found);
    printf("%lu\n", count);
    if (found) {
        // break;
    }
    number += count;
// }
```

This is the get_device_params function:

```
void get_device_params(device_params_t* params, cl_platform_id platform_id, const char *kernel_func, char *program_buffer, size_t program_size) {
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &params->device_count);
    params->device_ids = (cl_device_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id) * params->device_count);
    int err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, params->device_count, params->device_ids, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a device group! %d\n", err);
        free(params->device_ids);
        return;
    }

    int i;
    size_t local, min_local = 0;

    params->context = clCreateContext(NULL, params->device_count, params->device_ids, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a compute context!\n");
        goto out1;
    }

    cl_program program = build_program(params->context, params->device_ids, program_buffer, program_size);
    if (!program)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute program!\n");
        goto out1;
    }

    params->kernel = clCreateKernel(program, kernel_func, &err);
    if (!params->kernel || err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute kernel!\n");
        goto out1;
    }

    params->commands = malloc(sizeof(cl_command_queue) * params->device_count);

    for(i = 0; i < params->device_count; i++) {
        params->commands[i] = clCreateCommandQueue(params->context, params->device_ids[i], 0, &err);
        if (!params->commands[i])
        {
            printf("Error: Failed to create a command commands! %d\n", err);
            goto out1;
        }

        err = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(params->kernel, params->device_ids[i], CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(local), &local, NULL);
        if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Error: Failed to retrieve kernel work group info! %d\n", err);
            goto out1;
        }

        min_local = min_local > local ? local : min_local;
    }

    params->local = min_local;

    return;

    out1:
    if (params->kernel) {
        clReleaseKernel(params->kernel);
    }
    if (params->commands) {
        for(i = 0; i < params->device_count; i++) {
            clReleaseCommandQueue(params->commands[i]);
        }
    }
    if (params->context) {
        clReleaseKernel(params->context);
    }
    clReleaseProgram(program);

    return;
}
```

The run_on_gpu is defined as:

```
void run_on_gpu(device_params_t *device_params, PDFParams *params, unsigned long start, char *prefix, unsigned int prefix_length, char *suffix, unsigned int suffix_length, int password_length, const unsigned long cnt, bool *found)
{
    printf("size %lu\n", cnt);
}
```

Now what's happening is this:

```
9
size 549755813890
9
```

I expect it to be:

```
9
size 9
9
```

Not sure what's going on!

Comment: You have `printf("%lu")`, then `run_on_gpu`, then another `printf("%lu")` - looks like it's doing what it's supposed to?

Comment: @valiano the value being printed is different. in run_on_gpu the value is 549755813890, but it's expected to be 9

Comment: Got it. But shouldn't the expected output be `9`, `size 9`, `9`?

Comment: And just to verify, `password_length` == `cnt` == 9?

Comment: @valiano sorry, updated that. And no, password_length was something i added later, forgot to undo when pasting here. But the result is as described in the question

Comment: Thanks for updating. I would suggest adding `c` and `opencl` tags to the question, it may helps getting the right attention

Comment: Amit, start removing parameters (except count) from run_on_gpu one by one. When the problem goes away, you found your culprit.

Comment: `run_on_gpu` takes 10 parameters, and latter ones may be passed on the stack (just a theory). What happens when `cnt` becomes the first parameter?

Answer (score 2):

At a SWAG, there's a parameter mismatch in the use and definition of `run_on_gpu()`.  `549755813890` isn't very interesting till you view it as a 64 bit hex number.  At which point it becomes `0x00000080:00000002`, colon inserted between 32 bit groups.  That just screams at me that somehow the parameter `cnt` in `run_on_gpu()` is overlaying two other 32 bit values.

It's worth noting that this would be consistent with GCC on a 64 bit system, but not 32 bit GCC or MSVC on any platform.  To the best of my knowledge 64 bit GCC is the only "desktop" compiler that treats `unsigned long` as 64 bits, all others treat it as 32 bits.

Comment: Great observation! On the host side, one should alway use the cl_<type> types instead of "native" types; they are designed to be the same size as the device types.